# Error occured while deleting browser history from AsyncTask in Android

Tags: android, android-asynctask

I'm trying to delete the browser history using methods (called from `doInBackground()` method of `Asynctask`).

```
Browser.clearHistory(getContentResolver());
Browser.clearSearches(getContentResolver());
```

but these methods are giving an error that you can not call these method from non ui thread.

If someone has faced such problem, please suggest an answer.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to update the UI from a non-UI thread, you can use the [`runOnUiThread`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Activity.html#runOnUiThread%28java.lang.Runnable%29) method.

In your case, you can use the following code snippet:

```
runOnUiThread(new Runnable(){
  public void run(){
    Browser.clearHistory(getContentResolver());
    Browser.clearSearches(getContentResolver());
  }
});
```

Answer (score 0):

To achieve this you have to use a Handler in order to update your Browser from a non UI thread. Here is a good article from Lars Vogel describing how to do this

[Link](http://www.vogella.com/articles/AndroidPerformance/article.html)